# Getting all module names in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to list all the modules , controllers and actions included in my project for acl purpose. But i dont know how can i fetch such information from zf2. Anyone has an idea of how to make this work? ThankYou :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
$manager        = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
$modules        = $manager->getLoadedModules();
$loadedModules      = array_keys($modules);
$skipActionsList    = array('notFoundAction', 'getMethodFromAction');

foreach ($loadedModules as $loadedModule) {
    $moduleClass = '\\' .$loadedModule . '\Module';
    $moduleObject = new $moduleClass;
    $config = $moduleObject->getConfig();

    $controllers = $config['controllers']['invokables'];
    foreach ($controllers as $key => $moduleClass) {
        $tmpArray = get_class_methods($moduleClass);
        $controllerActions = array();
        foreach ($tmpArray as $action) {
            if (substr($action, strlen($action)-6) === 'Action' && !in_array($action, $skipActionsList)) {
                $controllerActions[] = $action;
            }
        }

        echo $loadedModule . "\n";
        echo $moduleClass . "\n";
        print_r($controllerActions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. One flaw in this solution is that you only retrieve the invokables from the serviceManager and not the factories. For the perfect solution he has to combine some ideas from your and my answer. I'm not really sure if aliases are also listed in the `getCanonicalNames`. If that is the case it is a matter of merging the invokables and factories keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a array of the loaded modules from the `ModuleManager`.

```
$moduleManager = $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager');
$loadedModules = $moduleManager->getLoadedModules();
```

For controllers you can retrieve them from the `ControllerManager`.

```
$controllerManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader');
foreach ($controllerManager->getCanonicalNames() as $alias) {
    $controller = $controllerManager->get($alias); // This will get you the controller instance
}
```

ZF2 doesn't have any convenience methods built in to retrieve all the controller actions. Using some reflection would be your best bet imo.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($controller);
$actions = array();
foreach ($reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
    $methodName = $method->getName();
    if ($methodName == 'getMethodFromAction') {
        continue;
    }
    if (substr_compare($methodName, 'Action', -strlen('Action')) === 0) {
        $actions[] = substr($methodName, 0, strlen($methodName) - 6);
    }
}
var_dump($actions);
```